# AWS Amplify Environment secrets not showing up on the front end

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I'm running a React App, the frontend code is stored in my GitHub repo, and I am running a deployment using AWS Amplify

I'm trying to store an API key using **AWS Systems Manager (SSM) Parameter Store** to store my Environment secrets using [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html). I was able to access the test environment variable. As it is considered a bad practice to store API keys as environment variables, I am trying to use **Parameter Store** in **AWS Systems Manager**. These are the steps I undertook:

1. Clicked **Create parameter** in **Parameter Store**
2. Added name which looks like this:
   `/amplify/myAppId/myBackendEnvironmentName/REACT_APP_SECRETS` To clarify, I grabbed the **App ID** and **environment name** from AWS Amplify home page - **Backend Environments** tab. It gives me the CLI command that would pull the environment to my local machine: `amplify pull --appId myAppId --envName myBackendEnvironmentName`
3. Selected `Secure String`
4. Selected KMS key source: `My current account`
5. KMS Key ID: `alias/aws/ssm` (It was preselected)
6. Popuplated the `value`
7. Updated the YML deployment script in **AWS Amplify home page -> App Settings -> Build settings** which looks like this (most of it was pre-populated, I only added the echo commands and assigned env variables):

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - echo $REACT_APP_TEST_VAR
        - echo $REACT_APP_SECRETS
        - echo ${REACT_APP_TEST_VAR}
        - echo ${REACT_APP_SECRETS}
        - REACT_APP_SECRETS=${REACT_APP_SECRETS}
        - REACT_APP_TEST_VAR=${REACT_APP_TEST_VAR}
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

**REACT_APP_TEST_VAR** is the env variable that shows up, the **REACT_APP_SECRETS** doesn't. Here is the part of the **Front end deployment log**:

```
2023-09-30T15:37:39.856Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
                                 # Starting phase: build
                                 # Executing command: echo $REACT_APP_TEST_VAR
2023-09-30T15:37:39.857Z [INFO]: ThisWillBeMyTets
                                 # Executing command: echo $REACT_APP_SECRETS
                                 # Executing command: echo ${REACT_APP_TEST_VAR}
                                 ThisWillBeMyTets
                                 # Executing command: echo ${REACT_APP_SECRETS}
                                 # Executing command: REACT_APP_SECRETS=${REACT_APP_SECRETS}
                                 # Executing command: REACT_APP_TEST_VAR=${REACT_APP_TEST_VAR}
                                 # Executing command: npm run build
2023-09-30T15:37:40.178Z [INFO]: > pullup-bars@0.1.0 build
                                 > react-scripts build
```

When I do `console.log(process.env)` on my deployed react app this is the output:

```
{
    "NODE_ENV": "production",
    "PUBLIC_URL": "",
    "FAST_REFRESH": true,
    "REACT_APP_TEST_VAR": "ThisWillBeMyTets"
}
```

I did everything in the same region.

Basically `process.env.REACT_APP_SECRETS` is `undefined`. I tried everything, read and re-read the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html), but I don't know how to access the secrets. There must be something I'm missing, any ideas?